# Count Results Based on Categorize Range Age (Query MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
| Results  | Age |
|----------------|
|    HT    | 20  |
|    HT    | 22  |
|    HT    | 55  |
```

How I can show the latest data like this:

```
|  RangeAge  | CountResult |
|--------------------------|
|    15-19   |      0      |
|    20-44   |      2      |
|    45-54   |      0      |
|    55-60   |      1      |
|    60-..   |      0      |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a derived table, in order to get the rows with a zero count:

```
select r.range, count(t.age)
from (select '15-19' as range, 15 as lo, 19 as hi  union all
      select '20-44' as range, 20 as lo, 44 as hi  union all
      . . . 
     ) r left join
     t
     on t.age >= r.lo and t.age <= r.hi
group by r.range
order by min(r.lo);
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, I just know that
'select '15-19' as range, 15 as lo, 19 as hi  union all ..' no need to 'select .. from union all ..' haha

Answer (score 1):

Here's your query;

```
select t1.* from (
    select '15-19' as rAge, count(1) as ct from tableA where Age between 15 and 19
    union all
    select '20-24', count(1) from tableA where Age between 20 and 24
    union all
    select '45-54', count(1) from tableA where Age between 45 and 54
    union all
    select '55-60', count(1) from tableA where Age between 55 and 59
    union all
    select '60', count(1) from tableA where Age > 59) t1
```

Comment: Thank you this worked too, I will choose the best and efficient for my program